# How to create sub group page with gitweb (or any other git web-server)?

Tags: git, gitosis, gitweb, git-server

I setup a gitosis server with gitweb and I have numbers of git projects there now.
Is there a way to organize these project by groups?

Say I have a group called "tools" and another group called "debug" and each group contains several projects related to their group name. I'd like to setup, so I can send user a link which contains only "tools" projects and another link to show all the "debug" projects.
Even better, if there is a web application that will parse my gitosis.conf file, since I can define multiple groups in the gitosis, if the web interface can generate different links based on the group defined in config file, that will be ideal.

Comment: I just discovered Gitorious, and looks like I can group projects by "tags". Though I have no experience setting up Ruby project, so this may take a while to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

[Gitblit](http://gitblit.com) supports grouping of repositories in subfolders but not tags.  If you were to only use Gitblit's http/https JGit servlet for cloning/pushing, then you can restrict repository access by user.  Not sure if that helps you out.